# ffmpeg start_time of silence_detect result is negative

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

When I use ffmpeg to detect audio silence, the start time of result is negative.

I want it starts from 0, who can help me?

```
D:\audiodrop>ffmpeg -i silence.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-27dB:d=1 -f null -

ffmpeg version 3.4.git Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 6.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)

  configuration:

  libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101

  libavcodec     58. 12.102 / 58. 12.102

  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100

  libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100

  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100

  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101

  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101

Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono

Input #0, wav, from 'silence.wav':

  Duration: 00:00:06.60, bitrate: 705 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.9.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.12.102 pcm_s16le

[silencedetect @ 000001ca9b8719c0] silence_start: -0.0247619

size=N/A time=00:00:06.60 bitrate=N/A speed=1.7e+003x
video:0kB audio:569kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Please update to a recent version of ffmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html (see static builds, for example).

Comment: @slhck thank you. The recent version is OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug in an older version of ffmpeg. Please download a recent one from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html instead. You can get a static build, which does not require compilation.